# update database with a new value at button submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have been struggling with this for a few days and i'm new to reactjs and javascript. I have a form that submit successfully to database then it redirect me to an other page where there is a Quiz to do. When you answer all the questions and click on "Apply", you submit the Quiz score by updating the database and add the score value. How to update database at button click?

Quiz.js:

```
function EndScreen() {
  const { score } = useContext(QuizContext);


  return (
    <div className='EndScreen'>
      <h1>Test finished</h1>
      <br></br>
      <h3> You scored:</h3>
      <h1 style={{ fontSize: '70px' }}>{score}/{Questions.length}</h1>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <button>Apply</button>                 //Clicking on this button should submit score to database
    </div>
  )
}
```

formServices.js:

```
export const FormService = {
  store: (data) => {
    console.log('data===>>>', data);

    const { title, fname, lname, email, phoneNumber, cv, coverLetter } = data;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fname', fname);
    formData.append('lname', lname);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
    formData.append('coverLetter', coverLetter);
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('cv', cv);

    Axios.post(requests.formApi.store, formData)
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  }
};
```

FormController.js:

```
const form = require('../models/FormModel')

module.exports = {
    store: (req, res, next) => {
        let candidate = new form({
            title: req.body.title,
            fname: req.body.fname,
            lname: req.body.lname,
            email: req.body.email,
            phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
            coverLetter: req.body.coverLetter,
            cv: req.body.cv,
            score: req.body.score
        })
        if (req.file) {
            candidate.cv = req.file.path
        }
        candidate.save()
            .then(response => {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Candidate added successfully!',
                    data: candidate,
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'An error occured!',
                    error: error,
                })
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: `<button onClick={() => FormService.store(data)}>Apply for job</button>`

Comment: @casraf thank's , that is logic, but my front console says `'data' is not defined`

Comment: You need to give it the correct data...

Comment: i guess the data should be score